# OpenCV template matching parameters

Tags: c++, opencv

In the following template matching code I don't understand what the following line is doing:

```
cv::Mat res(ref.rows-tpl.rows+1, ref.cols-tpl.cols+1, CV_32FC1);
```

The full code is:

```
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

int main()
{
    cv::Mat ref = cv::imread("ref.jpg");
    cv::Mat tpl = cv::imread("temp.jpg");
    if (ref.empty() || tpl.empty())
        return -1;

    cv::Mat gref, gtpl;
    cv::cvtColor(ref, gref, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    cv::cvtColor(tpl, gtpl, CV_BGR2GRAY);

    cv::Mat res(ref.rows - tpl.rows + 1, ref.cols - tpl.cols + 1, CV_32FC1);
    cv::matchTemplate(gref, gtpl, res, CV_TM_CCOEFF_NORMED);
    cv::threshold(res, res, 0.8, 1., CV_THRESH_TOZERO);

    while (true)
    {
        double minval, maxval, threshold = 0.8;
        cv::Point minloc, maxloc;
        cv::minMaxLoc(res, &minval, &maxval, &minloc, &maxloc);

        if (maxval >= threshold)
        {
            cv::rectangle(
                ref,
                maxloc,
                cv::Point(maxloc.x + tpl.cols, maxloc.y + tpl.rows),
                CV_RGB(0, 255, 0), 2
                );
            cv::floodFill(res, maxloc, cv::Scalar(0),
                0, cv::Scalar(.1), cv::Scalar(1.));
        }
        else
            break;
    }

    cv::imshow("reference", ref);
    cv::waitKey();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's creating the matrix that will contain the result of the matching.

According to the documentation for [matchTemplate](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/object_detection.html?#matchtemplate)

- **result** – Map of comparison results. It must be single-channel 32-bit floating-point. If image is  W x H and template is  w x h , then result is  (W-w+1) x (H-h+1).

With reference to your code:

```
image    -> ref
template -> tpl
W        -> ref.cols
H        -> ref.rows
w        -> tpl.cols
h        -> tpl.rows 

single-channel 32-bit floating-point -> CV_32FC1
```

However, since `matchTemplate` will create the result image, you don't need to create it. You can simply:

```
...
cv::Mat res;
cv::matchTemplate(gref, gtpl, res, CV_TM_CCOEFF_NORMED);
...
```

Comment: You mean it is creating something like a container for the result image right  ?

Comment: @user3072028 it's creating the result matrix. Each value of this matrix would be the distance (or similarity, according the used method), between the template and the image in that point.

Comment: Thanks for answer                                                                                    What i understood is that result like a border that will specify the region in the source image that matches the template

Comment: @sarmad as you can see [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html), the result is in the top left corner of the template. So you need a "border" to avoid to go too _right_ or too _down_ in the image. You can really ignore all of this, however, since you can simply avoid to create the result matrix in the first place.